Interpretation of log-transformed explanatory variable in Poisson regression
I need to interpret a coefficient in a Poisson model that is log-transformed. Let's call the coefficient log(1+EO). The coefficient estimate is 0.0651.
The mean of EO (i.e., not log transformed) is 0.505. The sd is 2.008.
I want to calculate the effect of a one standard deviation increase in EO.
I calculate a one standard deviation increase over the mean in log terms as follows:
ln(1+0.505+2.008)-ln(1+0.505)
I then calculate the economic significance of a one standard deviation increase in EO over the mean as: (exp(0.0651) -1) * 100 * (ln(1+0.505+2.008) - ln(1+0.505)) = 5.71%
Is this the correct way of doing it? I know that without a log transformation you would simply take exp(coeff) but the log transformation appears to complicate things.
Thanks a lot for any insights.

This will be a little tricky because the effect of a 1-SD change on the original (data) scale will now depend on the baseline value of the covariate.

But the mean should be a reasonable baseline value to use?

Or is there a less tricky approach to interpret the log-transformed coefficient in terms of the original data?

Was there some reason why you needed to use a log transformation of the EO predictor, which evidently has some values of 0? Using a regression spline instead of forcing a log transform on the values would generally be more reliable and get around a lot of the difficulties you now face. If you're looking for something simple with EO values that are necessarily non-negative, a square-root transform might be better than the log.

Yes, EO contains values of zero but is also right-skewed. Thus the log transformation.

You do not need to correct for skew of a predictor in a regression model. If you suspect a non-linear association between the predictor and outcome, a regression spline or other generalized additive model will be more useful for EO. Otherwise, you implicitly assume a strictly linear association between log(1+EO) and outcome, an assumption that might be very limiting and unlikely. See Section 2.4 of Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies or many pages on this site.

OK, thanks. I will consider this alternative approach. However, I would still be interested in knowing whether the calculations are correct (even if they depend on the baseline value i.e., a one standard deviation increase over the mean in this case).
